# Integration testing a function with a stream writer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stream, filesystems, nunit

I had a quick question for you guys, as I ran into a bit of a problem with integration testing a stream writer in C#. At my current position we consider any unit test which touches the file system a failure, not sure how that stacks up to other places as this is really my first coding position, but that's the case here. This leads me to using streams a lot rather than File.IO when reading from text files, as I can do something like:

```
private void ReadMe(Stream stream)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This allows me to toss in a memory stream during an integration test and free myself from the file system. This doesn't extend to the writing of a file though. For example:

```
private void WriteMe(Stream stream)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This will `Dispose` of a stream before I have any chance to see what's written, as it really should. Sadly that means I have to move my writing into small simple functions that are generally too simple to need testing, which is a touch annoying and ugly to read. I asked around the office, but no one has ever bothered to look for a way around that, and I was just wondering if there was a way to feed a memory stream to a writer and actually retain what was written for dissection at a later time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show an example of a test that demonstrates the issue you're describing? I have some thoughts on how to address your concrens, but want to make sure I stay on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

When the `StreamReader` is disposed, the `MemoryStream` will be too, but it will not delete it's content, so you still can do `MemoryStream.ToArray();`.

Only problem I can think is that for each test you should create a new `MemoryStream`.

Comment: You know, it's funny me and another coder were looking at this from all different angles just a few days ago trying to figure out how to sneak something past the disposal, and we never actually just tried dumping it out like that.. Worked like a charm though now I feel a bit silly. Thanks ^-^!